# why does my django application retain variables after program have been executed

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
def clean_html_1(soup, items=[],stripped_items=[]):
    text_list = []
    for div in soup.find_all("td", attrs={"height":"24", "style":" padding-left:15px", "width":"200"}):
        text_list.append(div.stripped_strings)
        for i in range(len(text_list)):
            for gen in text_list[i]:
                 items.append(gen)
    for x in items:
        if x != None:
            stripped_items.append(x.replace("\\", ""))
    if len(stripped_items) > 0:
        stripped_items.remove("Reference Code")
    print(stripped_items)
    return stripped_items

def process_data(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')
    items = clean_html_1(soup)
    it = iter(items)
    trans_details = dict(zip(it, it))
    return trans_details
```

When I run this code, the print stripped items give values like this

```
['Account Number', '232****313', 'Effective Date', 'Wednesday, June 17, 2020', 'Currency Naira', 'NGN', 'Description', 'MC DB NG Sd PayP Card Issuance Transfer | 48 | 17/06/2020', 'Reference Code', 'Branch', 'Head Office', 'Transaction Type', 'DEBIT', 'Date of Transaction', '17/06/2020 12:22:57 PM', 'Amount', '10,000.00', 'Current Balance', '4,000.00', 'Available Balance', '4,000.00']
```

But when I run it again in a few seconds, with an updated value, I get this

```
['Account Number', '232****313', 'Effective Date', 'Wednesday, June 17, 2020', 'Currency Naira', 'NGN', 'Description', 'MC DB NG Sd PayP Card Issuance Transfer | 48 | 17/06/2020', 'Reference Code', 'Branch', 'Head Office', 'Transaction Type', 'DEBIT', 'Date of Transaction', '17/06/2020 12:22:57 PM', 'Amount', '10,000.00', 'Current Balance', '4,000.00', 'Available Balance', '4,000.00', 'Account Number', '232****313', 'Effective Date', 'Wednesday, June 17, 2020', 'Currency Naira', 'NGN', 'Description', 'MC DB NG Sd PayP Card Issuance Transfer | 48 | 17/06/2020', 'Reference Code', 'Branch', 'Head Office', 'Transaction Type', 'DEBIT', 'Date of Transaction', '17/06/2020 12:22:57 PM', 'Amount', '10,000.00', 'Current Balance', '4,000.00', 'Available Balance', '4,000.00']
```

so, It is merging the values stripped item from previous website run with the new one and I only need the latest one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never use this kind of defaults in function parameters:

```
items=[],stripped_items=[]
```

Since functions are being evaluated upon definition, the dafault parameters are kind of function attributes. When function is defined this parameters being pre-evaluated and are used with whatever value (elements) they now store every time you call the function.

Use none params instead and define lists inside the function:

```
def clean_html_1(soup, items=None, stripped_items=None):
    items=[]
    stripped_items=[]
```

Check [this](http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm) article for some more explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Python's default parameters are generated only once when a function is defined, not every time it is called. This means that if you use the variable default parameter and change it, the result of all calls to the function is the mutable object

for example

```
def append_to(element, to=[]):
    to.append(element)
    return to
my_list = append_to(12)
print(my_list)
my_other_list = append_to(42)
print(my_other_list)
# The result
# [12]
# [12, 42]
```